# python's urllib.urlopen for javascript

Tags: javascript, python, urllib

Is there a module written in javascript that's equivalent to python's urllib?  In particular, I want something like:

```
urllib.urlopen(url, data)
```

which returns an object that supports a blocking fetch.  Alternatively, in what other ways could I perform a blocking request to a server using javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the normal XMLHttpRequest synchronously:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, false);  # third param is sync/async
xhr.send(data);
var response = xhr.responseText;
```